# Change vAxis label position

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to find a way to change the position of the labels on my vertical axis. By default, a line chart renders the labels to the left of the chart, I'd like them to display on the right instead. It seems as if this isn't possible but I'm not too aware of ways to extend the line graph implementation to make it behave like I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `series` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) to change the `targetAxisIndex`

the documentation says...

> `targetAxisIndex`: Which axis to assign this series to, where 0 is the default axis, and 1 is the opposite axis. Default value is 0; set to 1 to define a chart where different series are rendered against different axes. At least one series much be allocated to the default axis. You can define a different scale for different axes.

but seems to work without assigning anything to the *default* axis...

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');

    data.addRows([
      ['Label 1', 10],
      ['Label 2', 20],
      ['Label 3', 30],
      ['Label 4', 40]
    ]);

    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(data, {
      series: {
        0: {
          targetAxisIndex: 1
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```